# I'm having issues with returning false values to functions in PHP

Tags: php, forms, function, validation

This is a sample of individual functions that validate form data from a request submission. A variable of `true` has been set and each function checks for validation requirements then either continues without returning anything or returns `false` and changes the `$check` value. The function down the bottom then checks if the `$check` value has changed to `false` and if it has the SQL statement will not be run.

```
$check = true;

function productNameValidation(){

    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_name']) && preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 :]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 :]{0,50}$/",($_REQUEST['product_name']))){

        //then $valid['ID'] = "string: " . $_REQUEST['ID']
        $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
        $err['product_name'] = "No errors";
        //if not    
    } else {
        if(empty($_REQUEST['product_name'])){
            $valid['product_name'] = "No data entered!";
        } else {    
            $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
        } //$err['ID'] = "error message"

        $err['product_name'] = "Product Name must only contain letters, numbers and ':'!";
        $check = false; 
    }
}

function checkProduct()
{
    productNameValidation();
    productGenreValidation();
    productPriceValidation();
    productEsrbValidation();
    productThumbnailValidation();
    releaseDateValidation();

    return $check;
}
if($check == true)
{
   //Insert into database
}
```

Comment: Your functions operate on a set of shared variables, so these must be declared `global` in each function. Better yet, make a class from them and use object members (like `$this->err`) instead.

Comment: I suggest a few people here read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php some of the answers to this post could cause confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add different variables on different functions. If you are working this code to the method that it begins as `true` and is required to be checked and if the check fails then becomes false, try this method:

```
   // $check = true;

    function productNameValidation(){
        $nameValidation = TRUE;
        if(isset($_REQUEST['product_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_name']) && preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 :]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 :]{0,50}$/",($_REQUEST['product_name']))){

            //then $valid['ID'] = "string: " . $_REQUEST['ID']
            $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
            $err['product_name'] = "No errors";
            //if not    
        } else {
            if(empty($_REQUEST['product_name'])){
                $valid['product_name'] = "No data entered!";
            } else {    
                $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
            } //$err['ID'] = "error message"

            $err['product_name'] = "Product Name must only contain letters, numbers and ':'!";
            $nameValidation = false; 
        }
    return $nameValidation;
    }

    function checkProduct()
    {
    $checkProduct = true; ///true until proven false.

        $checkProduct = productNameValidation();
        //This code gives $checkProduct the boolean value returned 
    //from the function

       $checkProduct = productGenreValidation();
        $checkProduct = productPriceValidation();
        $checkProduct = productEsrbValidation();
        $checkProduct = productThumbnailValidation();
        $checkProduct = releaseDateValidation();

        return $checkProduct;
    }
    if($checkProduct  == true)
    {
       //Insert into database
    }
```

What I have done here is each function returns a `TRue`/`False` flag boolean variables which can be checked with an `if(){` statement, you can run through numerous functions in this way checking each aspect you need. The important point is that you need to return a value from each function and you can set the booleans manually with initial settings which is then updated upon conditionals - such as setting `$checkProduct = TRUE` until it is FALSE from any sub function.

Global variables are really not a good idea in this case.

Edit: Thanks to @Edward for some clarification of boolean return code.

Comment: You could even just set `$checkProduct` to the value of the validation function, that way you can check multiple functions without loads of if/else if clauses.

Comment: Ahhhh of course! That makes so much sense. Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: @daniel-schofield93 if this solves your problem tick the tick next to my answer, cheers :)

Comment: Cheers Martin! I will be sure to approach you with more questions about shopping carts :P haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
function productNameValidation(){
    $check = true;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_name']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_name']) && preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9 :]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 :]{0,50}$/",($_REQUEST['product_name']))){

        //then $valid['ID'] = "string: " . $_REQUEST['ID']
        $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
        $err['product_name'] = "No errors";
        //if not    
    } else {
        if(empty($_REQUEST['product_name'])){
            $valid['product_name'] = "No data entered!";
        } else {    
            $valid['product_name'] = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
        } //$err['ID'] = "error message"

        $err['product_name'] = "Product Name must only contain letters, numbers and ':'!";
        $check = false; 
    }
    return $check;
}

if(productNameValidation()) {
....
}
```

Comment: Setting the value of any variable has no affect on its scope. You need to either change the scope or return the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return $check` in your validation functions which will allow you to use the value of `$check` outside the function scope like this: `$check = productNameValidation()`. Another important note which I saw mentioned above: You should try to avoid the global scope as much as possible.

Answer (score -2):

You can use check like a local variable not global, so in function.
Instead if you want it as a global, at the beginning of the function, you have to specify that you referring to

```
global $check;
```

Comment: Using globals in this situation as a little over the top. Consider returning the variable instead.

Comment: There is no need for this value to be global, the value is better broken into variables for each scope.